# Recurrence Relation/Time Complexity for finding average height of a BST

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, recurrence

Say we have an initially empty BST where I perform n arbitrary inserts, how would I find the average height of this BST?  The expression/pseudocode for this would be (if I'm not mistaken):

```
H(T) = 1 + max(H(T.left), H(T.right))
```

My guess at a recurrence relation for this would be `T(n) = 1 + 2*T(n/2)`, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Now here's my dilemma, if my recurrence relation is correct, how do I calculate the average complexity for my average height algorithm?

Comment: This is not a simple recurrence relation. There are n! input sequences S_i.  Each produces a BST T(S_i), though multiple sequences can produce the same tree.  Each tree has a height H(T(S_i)).  You need to figure out ( sum_{i=0..n!} H(T(S_i)) ) / n!.  Now, how to compute H(T(s))?

Answer (score 0):

In general average case analysis is more complicated and you can't really use the same big-O techniques you would use in a normal worst-case proof. While your definition of height is correct, translating it to the recurrence will probably be more complicated then that. First off, you probably meant `T(n) = 1 + T(n/2)` (this would give a O(log n) height while your version gives O(n)) and then, nothing guarantees that values are evenly split 50-50 between right and left.

If you [search a bit](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=average+height+of+a+binary+search+tree) you will see that there is plenty of material out there on the average height of BSTs. For example, [one of the results I got](http://luc.devroye.org/devroye_1986_univ_a_note_on_the_height_of_binary_search_trees.pdf) said that the expected height of a BST tends to 4.3 * (log n) as n grows but goes through lots of complicated math to get there.

Answer (score 0):

T(n/2)+c
where c is some constant 
and we divide our array in two parts but we use only single part to search.if out ans is the larger then the middle value of then we only search in (mid+1.....j)
and if its smaller then the middle value then we only search in(i.....mid)
so, at time we only work with the single sub-array